# Java: Using applet JAR as a maven dependency with native libraries

Tags: java, maven, applet

This applet was run through javaws. The jnlp file allows me to download the base jar, as well as some native libraries, compacted in separate jars for each OS.
With java support ending for browsers, I wanted to allow the applet to run as a normal app on the client, but with a web server on top of it.

So far, I can call methods on the main/base jar. However, this jar calls `System.loadLibrary` to load such native libraries. However, I always get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.
The native library jars are dependencies of the project, and I've even tried extracting the dylib and dll files from the jars. I've set the java.library.path flag to the path where they're at.

Nonetheless, I still get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no library in java.library.path: /Users/me/java/apps`.
The web server I'm using is NanoHTTPD.

Can dependencies access local files? Do I need to give java permission to access the directory? Do I need to name the jars containing these native libraries accordingly?

I'm on MacOS (the lib files follow the naming convention "lib{{LIBRARY_NAME}}.dylib").

These third-party jars I’m using are signed
(base Java jar with Java classes and jars containing OS specific native libraries).

Comment: You might be interested in https://openwebstart.com/

Comment: *I've set the java.location.path flag to the path where they're at.* Never heard of that. What you need is `-Djava.library.path=/where/those/dylib/files/are` *These third-party jars I’m using are signed (base Java jar with Java classes and jars containing OS specific native libraries).* Yes, but that's no longer relevant. They were signed as their origin was the Web

Comment: @g00se yup, sorry. My mistake. That's the flag I set.
`-Djava.library.path="/Users/me/java/apps"` is what I'm using. Is that correct?


I have another app that uses an SDK as a library located somewhere else and that works just fine. I just can't figure out why these specific libraries can't be found.

Comment: There's not really enough detail. The path itself might be ok. It could be one of the dependent libraries is missing. Can you please post the full error verbatim

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no native_lib in java.library.path: /Users/me/java/apps
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2434)
 at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:848)
 at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2015)
 at com.me.WebInterface.ConnTest.main(ConnTest.java:9)`

Comment: @g00se: Also, if I use `System.load` with full path to library I get:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/me/java/apps/libnative_lib.dylib
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
 at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:785)
 at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1979)
 at com.me.WebInterface.ConnTest.main(ConnTest.java:9)`

Comment: I think you might be up against some problems with library types and system architecture and therefore not strictly  Java issues. You might be better also posting in OsX and C/C++

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/me/java/apps/libnative_lib.dylib` — And does that file exist?

Comment: @VGR yes it does. That’s why I have no idea what might be happening! I never had this issue.

Comment: Changing the Java SDK version seemed to do it. Thanks!